# TestNG suite failed

Tags: testng

I am trying to run my test with TestNG suite, it works fine when I have first two classes but as soon as I add third class "HomePageTest" it gives me

> NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after
>   calling quite()?

If I run this test individually it works without any error.

I have added my classes and testng.xml file here.

```
loginTest (Test#1)

package com.newtours.qa.testCases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.newtour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.FlightsPage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {

    LoginPage loginpage;
    FlightsPage flightspage;

    public LoginPageTest(){

        super();

    }

        @BeforeMethod()

        public void setUp(){
            initialization();

            loginpage = new LoginPage();


        }

            @Test(priority =1)
            public void verifyTitleTest(){
                String title =loginpage.verify_Mercury_ToursTitle();
                Assert.assertEquals(title, "Sign-on: Mercury Tours");

            }

            @Test(priority=2)
            public void loginTest(){

                flightspage =loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"),prop.getProperty("password"));

            }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){

        driver.quit();
    }
}

FlightsPageTest (test#2)
package com.newtours.qa.testCases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.newtour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.FlightsPage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.LoginPage;

public class FlightsPageTest extends TestBase{

    LoginPage loginpage;
    FlightsPage flightspage;
    HomePage homepage;

    public FlightsPageTest(){
        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        initialization();
        loginpage = new LoginPage();
        flightspage = new FlightsPage();
        flightspage =loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
        homepage = new HomePage();

    //flightspage = new FlightsPage();

    }

    @Test(priority =1)
    public void verifyFlightsPageTitle(){

        String title =driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Find a Flight: Mercury Tours:");

    }

    @Test(priority=2)

    public void clickOnHomepageLink(){

        homepage =flightspage.clickOnHomepageLink();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){

        driver.quit();
    }

}

HomePageTest (3rd class_ test fail when I add this class in xlm file).

package com.newtours.qa.testCases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.newtour.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.FlightsPage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.HomePage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.LoginPage;
import com.newtour.qa.pages.RegistrationPage;

public class HomePageTest extends TestBase {

     LoginPage loginpage;
     FlightsPage flightspage;
     HomePage homepage;
     RegistrationPage registrationpage;


    public HomePageTest(){
        super();
    }


    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        initialization();
        loginpage = new LoginPage();
        flightspage =loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
        flightspage = new FlightsPage();
        homepage =flightspage.clickOnHomepageLink();
        homepage = new HomePage();
        registrationpage = new RegistrationPage();
    }

    @Test(priority =1)
    public void homepageTitleVerification(){

        String title =driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Welcome: Mercury Tours");

    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void clickOnRegistrationPageLink(){

        registrationpage=homepage.registrationPageLink();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

}

testng.xml 

<suite name="newtourAutomationTest">
 <test name="newtour">
 <classes>
 <class name="com.newtours.qa.testCases.LoginPageTest" />
 <class name="com.newtours.qa.testCases.FlightsPageTest" />
 <class name="com.newtours.qa.testCases.HomePageTest" />

</classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple issues.

- you are running logins with the same user onto one application, this may or may not work. Some application allow unlimited multilogins, some only limited, some only one concurrently
- you are also terminating your driver after each method

suggestion:

keep one driver open for a longer period for multiple tests. E.g.

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeGroups
```